# A subgroup analysis in R

Tags: r, regression, survival-analysis, cox-regression

I am trying to carry out a subgroup analysis in R with a CPH regression. I essentially have lots of patients who have diabetes (Y/N) and a certain urine amount (>/<200ml). Looking to gauge the effect of this interaction on survival. I have managed to run the CPH for the diabetes group (across all urine amounts) using the below. I have also created subsets of the diabetes/urine amount combos (renamed the dataset for privacy).

```
# create new variable splitting above and below 200 ml urine amount
    xxxx$uacr200 <- ifelse(xxxx$uacr>=200,1,0)

# create a new categorical variable that combines diabetes status AND urine amount above and below 200
xxxx$dmuacrgr <- NA
xxxx$dmuacrgr[xxxx$uacr<200 & xxxx$diabfl=="N"] <- 1
xxxx$dmuacrgr[xxxx$uacr>=200 & xxxxl$diabfl=="N"] <- 2
xxxx$dmuacrgr[xxxx$uacr<200 & xxxx$diabfl=="Y"] <- 3
xxxx$dmuacrgr[xxxx$uacr>=200 & xxxx$diabfl=="Y"] <- 4

# create version of treatment variable that is coded as 1 and 0
xxxx$trt <- NA
xxxx$trt[xxxx$trt02pn==2] <- 1
xxxx$trt[xxxx$trt02pn==1] <- 0

xxxx_sub <- xxxx[,c("usubjid", "mageg1n","mgfrg1n","msexg1n","muacrg1n", "trt")]

#Diab subgroup analysis (across all urine amounts)

# fit cox model to estimate HRs in diabetes subgroups
cox_mod_diab <- coxph(Surv(aval, cnsr==0) ~ trt + trt*diabfl + diabfl +
                            mageg1n + mgfrg1n + msexg1n + muacrg1n + sitegr2n, 
                         data = zzzz, subset=(paramcd=="KDPDVASC"), ties="breslow")

    subg_cox_mod_diab <-            subgroupAnalysis(cox_mod_diab_int_KDPDVASC,zzzz[zzzz$paramcd=="KDPDVASC",],treatment="trt",
                                 subgroups=("diabfl"),confint.method="default")
```

I now just need to use the combo subsets I created above to find out what the diabetes effect is, across each urine amount....any help would really save me!!

Answer (score 0):

You created the subgroups as

```
xxxx$dmuacrgr <- NA
xxxx$dmuacrgr[xxxx$uacr<200 & xxxx$diabfl=="N"] <- 1
xxxx$dmuacrgr[xxxx$uacr>=200 & xxxxl$diabfl=="N"] <- 2
xxxx$dmuacrgr[xxxx$uacr<200 & xxxx$diabfl=="Y"] <- 3
xxxx$dmuacrgr[xxxx$uacr>=200 & xxxx$diabfl=="Y"] <- 4
```

I would suggest creating your data for subgroup analysis as follows:

```
subgroup_data <- xxxx[xxxx$dmuacrgr == 2,]
```

Then use it for your CPH

```
cox_model2 <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ cov1 + cov2, data = subgroup_data)
```

or use `strata(variable)`

```
cox_model <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ cov1 + cov2 + strata(dmuacrgr), data = data)
```

Then use `summary` to get hazards, CIs, etc.

```
summary(cox_model)
```

Comment: Thank you!! This is super useful - the only thing is, my covariates are pulled from another file with the outcome I am trying to measure survival for. So data = in the CPH won't be able to be the subgroup only. Is there a way around this? Thank you again!!

Comment: No way to merge the data?

Comment: I don't think so? It's a huge file (the original). The subgroups are created just for the script to run on. I was thinking an ifelse, conditional on the subgroup number? Like: #For diabfl = Y, xxxx$dmuacrgr=3,4 (i.e. >2)

df<-xxxx$dmuacrgr
DIAByuACR <- subset(df, xxxx$dmuacrgr > "2")